# .NET MAUI: passed object can't be accessed until after the XAML runs

Tags: c#, maui, maui-shell

### The Problem

I have an object that I'm passing from ViewModel A to ViewModel B.  The object has properties that are used in the XAML.  The problem is that I don't have access to the passed object until *after the XAML runs*.

Here's what I'd like to happen:
[image]

### My Current Code

Here's my ViewModel.  Note the `Appearing` method is is an *EventToCommandBehavior* method and runs before the XAML runs.  Also note that if I put the code that's in `Appearing` into the ViewModel's constructor I get the same behavior: if I put a break point on the first line of the `Appearing` method, `Object.FirstName` is `null`.

```
[QueryProperty("Object","Object")]
public partial class ViewModel: ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty] private Object object;
  [ObservableProperty] private string firstName;
  [ObservableProperty] private string lastName;
  [ObservableProperty] private string someOtherString;

  [RelayCommand]
  private async Task Appearing()
  {
     FirstName = Object.FirstName;
     LastName = Object.LastNamel
     SomeOtherString = Object.SomeOtherString;
  }

  // NOTE: WE COULD USE THE CONSTRUCTOR INSTEAD OF 'APPEARING' AND 
  // GET THE SAME RESULTS
  //public ViewModel()
  //{
  //   FirstName = Object.FirstName;
  //   LastName = Object.LastNamel
  //   SomeOtherString = Object.SomeOtherString;
  //}
```

Here's the XAML that DOESN'T get populated:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}"
                                        EventName="Appearing" />

    <Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherString}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

### The Object is passed correctly

I do eventually get access to the passed object.  For example, if I do this the labels get populated, but it's too little too late. If I put a break point over the first line in `TooLittleTooLate()`, the `Object.FirstNAme` is populated with the passed value.

```
[QueryProperty("Object","Object")]
public partial class ViewModel: ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty] private Object object;
  [ObservableProperty] private string firstName;
  [ObservableProperty] private string lastName;
  [ObservableProperty] private string someOtherString;

  [RelayCommand]
  private async TooLittleTooLate()
  {
     FirstName = Object.FirstName;
     LastName = Object.LastNamel
     SomeOtherString = Object.SomeOtherString;
  }
}
```

Along with this xaml:

```
<ContentPage>
    <Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherString}"/>
        <Button Text="Press Me" 
                Command={Binding TooLittleTooLateCommand}/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

When I do this and the user presses the button, the labels get populated, but *that's too late*!  I need the labels to be populated *before* the XAML runs for the first time.

I think I'm missing something really obvious, because I've done stuff like this before with no issues.

### EDIT: Solution

Yep, the problem was obvious.  Instead of binding to the property, I should have bound to the `Object.Property`.

Instead of this:

```
Label Text={Binding FirstName}/>
```

It should've been this:

```
Label Text={Binding Object.FirstName}/>
```

I'm not feeling too intelligent right now.

Comment: You have misspelled ObservableProperty

Comment: In my real code it is not misspelled.  I'm just showing pseudocode to save the reader from the tedium.  With that said, I'll fix the typo.  (That would fit the bill of "obvious", though, so good looking out!)

Comment: properties are not populated until after the constructor runs - this is probably true of OnAppearing too, but I'm not positive.  You should be able to bind directly to `Object` and when `Object` is set it will fire a `PropertyChanged` and update the UI without you needing to do anything

Comment: @Jason Yep, that's it.  It was something obvious.  I just needed to bind to `Object.Property` instead of what I was doing, just binding to `Property`.  In my defense, I'm not very intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason said that You should be able to bind directly to Object and when Object is set it will fire a PropertyChanged and update the UI.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
<ContentPage>
    <Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding Object.FirstName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Object.LastName}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Object.SomeOtherString}"/>
        <Button Text="Press Me" 
                Command={Binding TooLittleTooLateCommand}/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```